# The difference when converting WGS84 to EPSG:3857 in MapInfo and GDAL

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, openlayers, coordinates, mapinfo

Please help me solve the problem with the coordinate shift.
I have two TAB files, with coordinate systems - one in meters, the other in degrees.

GDAL says they are:

```
file A: LOCAL_CS["Nonearth",UNIT["Meter",1.0]] 
file B: GEOGCS["unnamed",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

An online conversion service says that:

```
file A: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) 
file B: WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
```

In file A, I have a polygon, in file B there is a point with coordinates in degrees:

```
13.685983, 6.276257
```

I want to convert it to the coordinate system of file A (in meters).
When converting to all online services using both GDAL and openlayers, it translates to the point:

```
1523516.658565399004146, 700071.198322909418494
```

And only in MapInfo does it correctly translate to a point:

```
1521811.2, 697887.6
```

**Question**: Why do such differences arise? Could this be due to the fact that
"degree" in GDAL `0.0174532925199433`, not `0.017453292519943295`?

Comment: With 6.276257, 13.685983 the results are reversed.  OpenLayers always using Lon/Lat format.

Comment: Your file A is using a NonEarth coordinate system which means it just using a cartesian coordinate system with no relation to the Earth. Do you know what coordinate system File A should be using?